# Getting the value of a radio button

Tags: php, mysql

When I add a new record to my database the value of the radio button is inserted successfully. However, when I go to edit the record on my edit.php page, the radio buttons are all unchecked.

How I ensure that the corresponding radio button is checked depending on what I selected.

I've tried many different things and none work. This is the latest attempt:

```
<?php $prohibition = $row['prohibition']; ?> 
Yes: <input type="radio" name="prohibition" value="Yes" <?php if($row['prohibition'] == "Yes") print "checked";?> /><br>
No:  <input type="radio" name="prohibition" value="No" <?php if($row['prohibition'] == "No") print "checked";?> />
```

Comment: View the source of the page and post that.

Comment: What is the output of `$row['prohibition']`?

Comment: Based on the small snippet of code... wouldn't `<?php if ($prohibition == 'Yes') { echo 'checked'; ?>` work? Of course it depends *entirely* on the output of `$row['prohibition']`

Comment: This code should work normally, try and view the source code or print the echo the value of `$prohibition  `

Comment: @Scott Thank You! your little snippet worked! I can go home happy now :)

Comment: Why are you putting literal `"Yes"` and `"No"` in your database? This is a pretty egregious anti-pattern. It's much better to use normalized values like `0` and `1` to represent this. Not only is that consistent in length, but it's not language specific and works well with default SQL and PHP logic. `WHERE prohibition` and `if ($row['prohibition'])` would then work automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the small snippet of code...

`<?php if ($prohibition == 'Yes') { echo 'checked'; } ?>` should work.

You've already defined the `$prohibition` variable so just check against that There's no reason to use the database output directly for the if statements.

Of course it depends entirely on the output of `$row['prohibition']`

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of $row['prohibition']? try to replace print by echo :

```
<?php $prohibition = $row['prohibition']; ?> 
Yes: <input type="radio" name="prohibition" value="Yes" <?php if($row['prohibition'] == "Yes") echo "checked";?> /><br>
No:  <input type="radio" name="prohibition" value="No" <?php if($row['prohibition'] == "No") echo "checked";?> />
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `print` instead of `echo`?

Comment: They are both used to output data to the screen. The differences are small: echo has no return value while print has a return value of 1 so it can be used in expressions. echo can take multiple parameters (although such usage is rare) while print can take one argument. echo is marginally faster than print.